# Is there a way to ignore subqueries when there is no data to return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have the following query:

```
Comic.join(:publishercomics).where("publisher_id = 1 AND (rating < 5 OR rating IS NULL) AND comics.id NOT IN (:favorites)", {:favorites => User.find_by_id(current_user_id).favorites.where("top_10 = true").map(&comic_id)})
```

current_user_id is set to 0 when there is no logged in user, otherwise it is set to the ID of the currently logged in user.  I attempted this because I was hoping that I would not have to write two queries, one for when a user is logged in and one for not.  In generally it would seem useful to be able to write a query that sort of skips over the fact that there is no record found, and stops trying to join on non-existant data.  If I were to write this SQL directly, this would be pretty easy :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM comics c
INNER JOIN publishercomics pc ON pc.publisher_id = 1 AND pc.comic_id = c.id
WHERE comics.id NOT IN (SELECT comics_id FROM favorites WHERE user_id = current_user_id AND top_10 = true)
AND (c.rating < 5 OR c.rating IS NULL)
```

This question may extend to a general case - is there a way to make rails queries behave a bit more like SQL so that when part of a query returns no data, the entire query does not fail?  So that "User.find_by_id(0).favorites" would just return no records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Comic.join(:publishercomics).where("publisher_id = 1 AND (rating < 5 OR rating IS NULL) AND comics.id NOT IN (:favorites)", {:favorites => User.find_by_id(current_user_id).nil? ? [0] : User.find_by_id(current_user_id).favorites.where("top_10 = true").map(&comic_id)})
```

or

```
user = User.find_by_id(current_user_id)
Comic.join(:publishercomics).where("publisher_id = 1 AND (rating < 5 OR rating IS NULL) AND comics.id NOT IN (:favorites)", {:favorites => user.nil? ? [0] : user.favorites.where("top_10 = true").map(&comic_id)})
```

Comment: This work if you use [0] instead of [].  When you use [], rails generates "videos.id NOT IN (NULL)", which does not work the way one might expect.  It will never return rows.

I cannot edit your post because adding the 0s does not meet the requirements.  How is the usual way this works, should I mark your answer as correct even if it is not?

I should add I only tried the first example, but the second should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way this query can fail.  If the user exists, but there are no favorites associated with the user.

At first I tried to add :

```
User.find_by_id(like_user_id).favorites.nil? ? [0]
```

like so :

```
Comic.join(:publishercomics).where("publisher_id = 1 AND (rating < 5 OR rating IS NULL) AND comics.id NOT IN (:favorites)", {:favorites => User.find_by_id(current_user_id).nil? ? [0] : User.find_by_id(like_user_id).favorites.nil? ? [0] : User.find_by_id(current_user_id).favorites.where("top_10 = true").map(&comic_id)})
```

But this does not work because the 'favorites' are somehow not nil.  I don't quite understand how this works.  So instead I used :

```
User.find_by_id(like_user_id).favorites.count == 0 ? [0]
```

And this seems to work.